# Sort List Items based on array

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable

My website generates this List Items retrieving data from database:

```
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
    <li id="2" data-order="2" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" >Data</li>
    <li id="5" data-order="5" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" >Data</li>
    <li id="15" data-order="15" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" >Data</li>
    <li id="23" data-order="23" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" >Data</li>

</ul>




function loadData(){
            $("#ajaxLoader").show();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"getItinerari.php"
            }).done(function(itinerario_out){
                //console.log(itinerario_out);
                var route = JSON.parse(itinerario_out);
                for(var i in route){
                    var sortableDiv = '<li id="'+ route[i].it_id +'" data-order="'+ route[i].it_id +'" class="ui-state-default" style="">'+ route[i].itinerario +'<a href="edit.php?id='+ route[i].it_id +'"><img src="../images/file_edit.png" alt="Modifica" width="35px" height="auto"></a><a onclick="return deleteConferme();" href="delete.php?it_id='+ route[i].it_id +'"><img src="../images/delete.png" alt="Elimina" width="35px" height="auto"></a></li>';
                    $("#sortable").append(sortableDiv);

                }


                /****sortable*****/
                $('#sortable').sortable({


                    update: function(event, ui) {
                        var arr = $(this).sortable('toArray');
                        var i, n;
                        var datapost = [];
                        for (i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
                            datapost.push($('#' + arr[i]).data('order'));
                        }

                    $.post('saveSortable.php', {list: datapost}, function (o) {
                        alert(o);
                    });

                    }


                });
                /****sortable*****/





                $("#ajaxLoader").hide();
            });
            //fine done

        }
```

Those items are sortable so i can get from the DB an array with the last items order.

var sorted = [23, 5, 15, 2];

How can I on the next page load sort the items according by this array?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the array using `Array.prototype.forEach()`, `.appendTo()` to append the elements to parent element in order of array elements

```js
var sorted = [23, 5, 15, 2];
sorted.forEach(function(id) {
  $("#" + id).appendTo("#sortable")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
  <li id="2" data-order="2" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">Data 2</li>
  <li id="5" data-order="5" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">Data 5</li>
  <li id="15" data-order="15" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">Data 15</li>
  <li id="23" data-order="23" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">Data 23</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, i was not so clear. Elements are already append to the parent

Comment: @user3187960 Yes,  `.appendTo()` re-appends the elements to the parent element in the order corresponding the value of the element of the array `sorted`